# Connect to DB2 from Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, db2

I am trying to connect a Java program to IBM's DB2 database, here is the code

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();
Connection db2Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/N","R","k");
Statement st=db2Conn.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO NTTP VALUES('MANOJ SAINI','iskcon110','Rajasthan','Male','july 2 2014','C')");
```

I get a syntax error at `Statement st = db2Conn.createStatement();`

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.Statement to java.beans.Statement
```

and more at `st.executeUpdate()`, as Multiple markers at this line

```
    - The method executeUpdate(String) is undefined for the type Statement
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
     Assignment
    - MANOJ cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation.
```

I am new to DB2 and can not figure out what is wrong.

Comment: That's not literally what you have in the source, is it? The quotes in your SQL would be escaped. You must have an import statement toward the top importing java.beans.Statement.

Comment: When you are pasting code, please use exact source and error messages you are getting. For your issue first change import to java.sql.Statement, then debug rest of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax might work in a SQL REPL, but in Java those aren't valid String(s) - also you need to escape `\` because it's a special character in Java,

```
java.sql.Statement st=db2Conn.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate(
       "INSERT INTO NTTP VALUES('MANOJ SAINI','iskcon110',"
     + "'Rajasthan','Male','july 2,2014',"
     + "'C:\\Users\\Ramveer\\Documents\\res')");
```

Also, you should consider using [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and bind parameters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the error suggest that you are trying to import Statement from `java.beans.Statement` instead of `java.sql.Statement` and second thing try using `java.sql.PreparedStatement` instead of `java.sql.Statement`

Something like this :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO student(student_id,student_name,class) VALUES(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
statement.setInt(1, 7);
statement.setString(2,"MANOJ SAINI");
statement.setString(3,"Rajasthan");
```